# How to undo a deleted report

Tags: reports

I created a report to log in our donations however this morning when I deleted a batch it has deleted the entire report template and I now have empty contribution batches with just the amounts and not the donors information.

I urgently need this restored as we have used this report for logging in all our donations.

Please can someone help me asap.

Many thanks,

Grace

Comment: Several things I don't follow here ... you deleted a 'batch' - do you mean an 'accounting batch' (see the Contributions menu)?  If not, please clarify what you deleted and how you did it.  Deleting contribution data could affect the content of your report, but not the report template itself.  Also, Reports are for getting data out of Civi but you refer to using them to 'log in our donations' - do you mean to export contribution data from Civi to import to a financial accounts system?  What version of Civi are you running?  Do you have a recent backup?

Answer (score 1):

1. Look in Search >Advanced Search
2. Put in Search parameters that would show the lost donor data
3. Down in the bottom right-hand corner of the Search Criteria box check Search in Trash
4. You should be able to check all and then under actions restore.